# Large DBML (Linq-to-SQL) gets corrupted when edited

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql, dbml

I have a large DBML and when I edit something, it gets corrupted.

I digged a into the problem and found that when I save the edited DBML file, it creates a new designer file, with a 1 added to the end of the name. The original designer file and the new designer file are identical except for the changes made.

[image]

To fix the problem, I have to copy the contents of the xxxx1.Designer file into the original one and then delete the xxxx1.Designer file.

The designer file has OVER 68,000 lines of code. Is there anyway I can solve this bug?

Thanks
JP

Comment: VS version? .Net version? Maybe it's some memory boundary, no idea. Looks like you better split up the context into two or more contexts across natural aggregates in the database. Maye it's also time to fade-in Entity Framework.

Comment: VS 2019, .NET Frameworks 4.7.2
I agree with you to move on to EF, but it's such a big project that it cannot be done quickly.

Comment: Of course, but you could make a start with new tables/functionality. Both data layers can coexist happily in one application.

Comment: Hi @GertArnold
The problem is that the project is almost done and the changes are not new tables, but new or amended columns.
Also, the forms must be amended to cater for EF now.